# How determine $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is another problem I have been struggling with. Can someone help please? 
Let $f(z)$ be analytic for all $z$ and satisfy $f(z+1)=f(z)$ and $f(z+i)=f(z)$ for all $z$. Determine $f(z)$.

Comment: Use LaTeX.......!

Comment: Hint: the range of a certain compact square is the whole range of $f$, whence bounded. So this is Liouville again, like in the other exercise.

Comment: Ok,Thanks for the help

Comment: By the way, in what book are the questions in?

Comment: Are you asking us where your questions come from?

Comment: I though this was a problem form a book. That's why